# How to learn programming in unix environment? Shall I learn shell firstly?

Tags: shell, unix

I have learned the standard c and c++ language. However I don't know how to using system calls and writing programs with processes and so on.So I want to learn programming in the unix/linux environment .  What's the step? should I do. Should I learn the shell first.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard" C and C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in Systems Programming right now, and the professor is giving us a survey of Unix, including system calls and writing simpler versions of existing core utilities.

One source I found very helpful was reading the [full source code](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) of the utilities and a [system call](http://www.digilife.be/quickreference/QRC/LINUX%20System%20Call%20Quick%20Reference.pdf) quick reference.  The textbook is [Understanding UNIX/Linux Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130083968) and I definitely recommend you pick it up.

We haven't gotten into shell scripting at all, other than using input redirects, grep, and pipes, so I don't know how useful that would be for you at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program in a UNIX environment, you'll have to first learn your way around it before messing with system calls and stuff. I'd recommend [The UNIX programming environment](http://openlibrary.org/works/OL4617636W/The_UNIX_programming_environment) for a healthy introduction to UNIX in general. It's a little dated but still a gem of a book and a must read for any programmer.

Comment: Wonderful book, and fun to read. But it is more than a little dated. My father had cause to learn Unix programming a few years ago and being a methodical person, he checked from the library and read it before asking me for help. I'd say if caused as about as much confusion as it cleared up. Still, it *is* a good read.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Unix/Linux system, you should at least know a bit of shell scripting and its tools, just for the sake of knowing what your startup scripts does or quickly moving around your system (eg using ls, mv, cp etc). other than that, for real programming stuff, you can use a programming language (Python, Ruby comes to mind). A lot of modern programming langauge, like Python, already provides system level APIs. Python comes with a shell itself, so if you are a hard core, you can also use it for your every day tasks. This little example shows you can do directory listing in Python shell

```
>>> import os                                                         
>>> os.chdir("/tmp")                                                  
>>> os.listdir(".")
```

Its the same as typing `ls` on the command line. how about moving/copying files? Instead of using shell `mv` and `cp`,

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copy("file","/destiation")
>>> shutil.move("file1","/destination")
```

IMHO, if you plan to program system/low level stuff, then C/C++ may be what you need, but for normal system administrative or every day operations, a programming language like Python/Ruby (or Perl) would mostly suit you.

Comment: Yes,I am learning python now. Do you have any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to learn shell.
Just look for a book or web page describing unix system calls for C.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be programming in a "traditional" unix environment (i.e. using a text editor and doing everything from the command line), you will want to be pretty competent with the shell, and very competent with The Editor Of Your Choice (and you have freedom of choice, but if it's not emacs you're going to the bad place...).

But it isn't really necessary to "study" the shell *first*. Just be aware that the shell provides powerful tools. Then, every time you find you self thinking *"There has got to be a better way!"*, go learn what the better way *is*.